# Attempting to export SQL Server DB to Azure and get errors: External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

When attempting to deploy my on-prem SQL Server DB to Azure, I get a slew of errors. I do this simply by right clicking the DB in question, and then going to tasks, and then Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database. I am wondering if there is a workaround that is needed to try to bypass these or what is it that I need to do? I was under the assumption that the process was as simple as that, but I am unsure where to go at this point.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71564: Error validating element [linker-SQLRS01]: The element [linker-SQLRS01] has been orphaned from its login and cannot be deployed.
Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[vw_UserAccess]: View: [dbo].[vw_UserAccess] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_admin]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[vw_UserAccess]: View: [dbo].[vw_UserAccess] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_admin].[fldUsername]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[vw_UserAccess]: View: [dbo].[vw_UserAccess] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_admin].[fldActive]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld2]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld3]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[FourDigitSSN]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[ID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld1]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld5]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld6]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld4]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld8]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld9]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld7]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld2]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld3]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[FourDigitSSN]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[ID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld1]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld5]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld6]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld4]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld8]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld9]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_ProcessOrder_Backup] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[Fld7]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[fldCOMPANY]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[mms_tbl_employer].[ID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerName]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[DataDate] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ImportDate]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[PreviousImportDate]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[RecordCount]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[PreviousRecordCount]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[DataImportName] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ImportDate]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@profile_name]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@recipients]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@body]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@subject]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_DatasourceAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@body_format]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[job_id], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[sj] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[sj]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[sjs], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[job_id] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[sjs]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[sjs], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[schedule_id], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[sjs] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[sjs]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[ss], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[ss], [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[schedule_id] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[ss]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[name], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[sj], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[sj] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[sj]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[freq_recurrence_factor], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[freq_recurrence_factor] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[freq_recurrence_factor]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[freq_type], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[freq_type] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[freq_type]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[freq_interval], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[freq_interval] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[freq_interval]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[Freq_interval], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[Freq_interval] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[Freq_interval]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[freq_subday_type], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[freq_subday_type] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[freq_subday_type]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[freq_subday_interval], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[freq_subday_interval] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[freq_subday_interval]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[active_start_time], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[active_start_time] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[active_start_time]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[next_run_date], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[next_run_date] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[next_run_date]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[enabled], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[sj], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[sj] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[sj]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[next_run_date], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[next_run_date] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[next_run_date]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_VTJobSchedule] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs].[Next_run_time], [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules].[Next_run_time] or [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules].[Next_run_time]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_AutoImportPopEmail]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_AutoImportPopEmail] has an unresolved reference to object [master].[dbo].[INVOKE_WEB_PAGE]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerName]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ImportDate]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[RecordCount]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ImportDate]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@profile_name]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@recipients]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@blind_copy_recipients]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@body]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@subject]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@body_format]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts_HonorHealth]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts_HonorHealth] has an unresolved reference to object [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts_HonorHealth]: Procedure: [dbo].[sp_Send_EmailAlerts_HonorHealth] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[ds] or [EVN].[dbo].[DataSources].[EmployerID]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the database you are trying to export and the database named "EVN"? Are they different (which is my guess)? Or if the same, does your code use three-part names for no reason? In addition, there are features that are not supported in azure sql server - you will need to find alternatives. That includes email and the agent (those job tables)

Comment: @SMor it is a blank DB, brand new DB. I am just right clicking the source DB and going through the GUI. There is no code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the columns of the `[mms_tbl_employer]` and other mentioned tables, it says that has a unresolved reference to a object. It means some of the `views` and `procedures` of project were dependent on [ENV] database and only single database was being deploy to SQL Azure. DACFx must block Export when object definitions (views, procedures, etc.) contain external references, as **Azure SQL Database does not allow cross-database external references. So, this error was coming.**

There isn't any support available for this error in SSMS. But in Visual Studio (2013) with SSDT this can be resolved: Within VS, go to **SQL Server Object Explorer**, connect to the server, right click on the database, **Extract Data-tier Application**, and then adjust the **Extract Settings**, one of which is **"Verify extraction"**.

Comment: _"Azure SQL Database does not allow cross-database external references. So, this error was coming."_ - well, it does, via PolyBase and `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE...` - but not via db-qualified object names.

Comment: After exporting via this method can you import it to Azure SQL via this method or will you have to remove references to all cross database references.